# Rails + Apache solr taxonomy integration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, tree

I am little bottle-necked with design approach to my application. My plan is to create model Product and add filter, that uses Country, Region and City.

Country -> Region -> City are one to many relations respectively.

How well does apache solr handle tree strucures like these and how fast they are? Is it better to use something like ancestry for Solr https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry or it is better to seperate models for City, Region and Country?

System will need to handle a lot of requests and this tree can become very gigantic.

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Neo4j, a graph database?

It [supports Rails](http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/guides/rails3.html).
It [supports Lucene query syntax](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-search.html).

***Friendly advice:*** 
*I had huge performance problems some 5 years back, while trying to fit a large tree into a relational db. After replacing it with Neo4j a SP computation time went from 4 hours to 0 (the need for it simply vanished since I suddenly could do all relationship-based algebra in the run time).*

Comment: Thank you for advice, ill surely will consider using Neo4j